# Pulling player stats using NHL api

Tags: javascript, html

I was looking for some help getting player stats from this NHL api for each player clicked like this:
[player stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7AUQ.png). Ive been stuck on this for 2 weeks now, so any help would be so greatly appreciated.

I have it doing what I want if i pipe the teams roster link as the endpoint in the fetch, but not if i pass a teams link through my function.

When the teams link is passed, this is the error i get:
GET https://statsapi.web.nhl.comundefined/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

And this is my code in question:

```js
function displayPlayerStats(e, teamLink) {
  fetch(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com${teamLink}`) // /api/v1/teams/14/roster
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
    //console.log(data);
    if (e.target.id == 'player-name') {
      let name = e.target.text.trim();
      console.log(name);
      data.roster.map(player => {
        if (name == player.person.fullName) {
          getPlayerStatsByID(player.person.id);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

If you replace `${teamLink}` in the fetch with the roster link commented out next to it, it works for the Tampa Bay Lightning.

My fiddle of the full project is here if it helps: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naynayren/3pa4g0so/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize async/await to create a form that populates drop-downs in a synchronized way.

```js
const api = {
  baseUrl: 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1'
};

const triggerEvent = (el, eventName) => {
  const event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  event.initEvent(eventName, true, false);
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
};

const emptySelect = (select) => {
  for (let i = select.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    select.remove(i);
  }
}

const populateSelect = (select, data, keyFn, textFn) => {
  emptySelect(select);
  data.forEach(item =>
    select.add(new Option(textFn(item), keyFn(item))));
  return select;
};

const populateForm = (form, fields) =>
  Object.entries(fields).forEach(([key, value]) =>
    form[key].value = value);

const populateSeasons = (select) => {
  const year = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
  const seasons = new Array(50).fill('').map((_, index) => ({
    start: year - index - 1,
    end: year - index
  }));
  return populateSelect(select, seasons,
    season => `${season.start}${season.end}`,
    season => `${season.start} – ${season.end}`);
}

const fetchTeams = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(`${api.baseUrl}/teams`);
  const json = await response.json();
  return json.teams.sort((a, b) =>
    a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
}

const fetchRoster = async(teamId) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${api.baseUrl}/teams/${teamId}/roster`);
  const json = await response.json();
  return json.roster.sort((a, b) => {
    const n1 = a.jerseyNumber ? parseInt(a.jerseyNumber, 10) : 100;
    const n2 = b.jerseyNumber ? parseInt(b.jerseyNumber, 10) : 100;
    const res = n1 - n2;
    if (res !== 0) return res;
    return a.person.fullName
      .localeCompare(b.person.fullName, 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' });
  });
}

const fetchPlayer = async(playerId) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${api.baseUrl}/people/${playerId}`);
  const json = await response.json();
  const [player] = json.people;
  return player;
}

const fetchStats = async(playerId, seasonId) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${api.baseUrl}/people/${playerId}/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=${seasonId}`);
  const json = await response.json();
  let seasonStats;
  try {
    const { stats: [{ splits: [{ stat }] }] } = json;
    seasonStats = stat;
  } catch (e) {
    seasonStats = {};
  }
  const season = seasonId.match(/^(\d{4})(\d{4})$/).slice(1).join(' – ');
  const { shots, assists, goals, timeOnIce } = seasonStats;
  return { season, shots, assists, goals, timeOnIce };
}

const formatPlayerOptionText = (player) =>
  `${player.jerseyNumber || ''} – ${player.person.fullName} (${player.position.abbreviation})`

const onTeamChange = async(e) => {
  const teamId = e.target.value;
  const roster = await fetchRoster(teamId);
  const playerSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="roster"]');

  populateSelect(playerSelect, roster,
    player => player.person.id,
    formatPlayerOptionText);

  triggerEvent(playerSelect, 'change');
};

const onPlayerChange = async(e) => {
  const seasonSelect = document.forms['nhl']['season'];
  const playerId = e.target.value;
  const player = await fetchPlayer(playerId);

  populateForm(document.forms['player-info'], {
    'first-name': player.firstName,
    'last-name': player.lastName,
    'birth-date': player.birthDate,
    'current-team': player.currentTeam.name,
    'primary-number': player.primaryNumber,
    'primary-position': player.primaryPosition.type
  });

  triggerEvent(seasonSelect, 'change');
};

const onSeasonChange = async(e) => {
  const playerSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="roster"]');
  const seasonId = e.target.value;
  const stats = await fetchStats(playerSelect.value, seasonId);

  populateForm(document.forms['player-stats'], {
    'stat-season': stats.season,
    'stat-shots': stats.shots || 'N/A',
    'stat-assists': stats.assists || 'N/A',
    'stat-goals': stats.goals || 'N/A'
  });
}

const main = async() => {
  const nhl = document.forms['nhl'];
  const teamSelect = nhl['teams'];
  const playerSelect = nhl['roster'];
  const seasonSelect = nhl['season'];

  populateSeasons(seasonSelect);

  const teams = await fetchTeams();

  populateSelect(teamSelect, teams, team => team.id, team => team.name);

  teamSelect.addEventListener('change', onTeamChange);
  playerSelect.addEventListener('change', onPlayerChange);
  seasonSelect.addEventListener('change', onSeasonChange);

  teamSelect.value = 14;           // Tampa Bay
  seasonSelect.value = '20192020'; // 2019-2020

  triggerEvent(teamSelect, 'change');
};

main();
```

```css
:root {
  --background-color: #111;
  --background-color-alt: #222;
  --primary-font-color: #DDD;
  --input-background-color: #222;
  --input-font-color: #EEE;
}

body {
  background: var(--background-color);
  color: var(--primary-font-color);
  padding: 0.5em;
}

input,
select {
  background: var(--input-background-color);
  color: var(--input-font-color);
}

input[type="text"]:disabled {
  background: inherit;
  border: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

hr {
  border-color: var(--background-color-alt);
}

.entry {
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.entry:nth-child(even) {
  background: var(--background-color-alt);
}

.entry label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.results {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h1>NHL Player Stats</h1>
<form name="nhl">
  <div class="entry">
    <label>Team</label>
    <select name="teams"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <label>Player</label>
    <select name="roster"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <label>Season</label>
    <select name="season"></select>
  </div>
</form>
<hr />
<div class="results">
  <div>
    <h2>Info</h2>
    <form name="player-info">
      <div class="entry">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first-name" autocomplete="off" disabled />
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="last-name" autocomplete="off" disabled />
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <label>Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="text" name="birth-date" autocomplete="off" disabled />
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <label>Current Team</label>
        <input type="text" name="current-team" autocomplete="off" disabled />
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <label>Jersey Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="primary-number" autocomplete="off" disabled />
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <label>Position</label>
        <input type="text" name="primary-position" autocomplete="off" disabled />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Stats</h2>
    <form name="player-stats">
      <div class="entry">
        <label>Season</label>
        <input type="text" name="stat-season" autocomplete="off" disabled />
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <label>Shots</label>
        <input type="text" name="stat-shots" autocomplete="off" disabled />
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <label>Assists</label>
        <input type="text" name="stat-assists" autocomplete="off" disabled />
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <label>Goals</label>
        <input type="text" name="stat-goals" autocomplete="off" disabled />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your js has some things that I am not familiar with, but I keep going back over it to try and get a bit more understanding of what's happening. Async/Await is still extremely new to me. I'm slowly getting it. I'll rebuild mine going from this as a template as I do like what you've done to it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, your variable is undefined. Looking through your full code, it looks like you're only passing one argument to `displayPlayerStats` but it's expecting two. This should work for the case when you're calling the function in `getRosterByID:` function displayPlayerStats(teamLink) {`. You're also calling it in a click handler, but there's no` teamLink` available at that part of the code, so that one will fail.

Comment: So each team has a dedicated endpoint for their roster list i.e. /api/v1/teams/14/roster the only difference between each team is the id, the 14, that varies from team to team. I've tried cutting the id out and just putting that in the same way as the full link, still the same error. And all the dedicated links begin with a slash /. I can plop the link above in the fetch url and it works.

Comment: Got it. The `undefined` issue is still a problem though — that's happening because somewhere `getRosterByID` is getting called with `undefined`, either the `team.id` on line 118 or `data.teams[i].id` on line 81.

Comment: How is that? If it works with the actual link added to the end of the url and doesn't return undefined? I'm genuinely confused.

Comment: It's not that the code in the fetch wrapper function is failing, it seems to be that code somewhere else passing the `teamLink` argument is passing an `undefined`. Hence why it works when testing the function alone. You would need to look deeper at the places where it's being called.

Comment: Ah ok thank you for the explanation. It seems I'll dig a bit more then.

Comment: I am at a complete loss on how to get this going. Thank you for your help and insight though.

Comment: A good place to start would be by `console.log`ing `team.id` and `data.teams[i].id` above the function calls, and/or logging the `teamId` argument inside the function body.

Comment: console.log of team.id, data.teams[i].id and teamID all show the same id of 14 (for the Lightning) or any team i select, they all log the appropriate id's.

Comment: @NateM. I'm sorry, I was looking at totally the wrong function in your full code, that's not even the problematic function. I edited my answer. `displayPlayerStats` wants two arguments and you're only passing one.

Comment: hey no worries. if i pass the e for the event as the second argument i get this error: scripts.js:152 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at scripts.js:152

Comment: The function is looking for both an event and a teamLink. The event is provided at the bottom of your code in the click handler, an the teamLink is provided further up in getRosterByID. It would take some refactoring to make it only accept one. It looks like the click is used to eventually call `getPlayerStatsByID`, so it could probably be completely removed from `displayPlayerStats` — that would mean saving `data.roster` to somewhere outside of the function though. You should also really take a look at Mr Polywhirl's answer — it really cleans everything up and makes it more manageable.

Comment: Ok thank you, I've been looking at Mr. Polywhirl's response. That is a bit away from my understanding, although I'm trying to see what he's got going on. I didn't want to have to go back and rebuild it all, but it looks like that might be the case if I can't get it going how I have it.